Jenkins JCASC: Remote Triggering a (Declarative)Pipeline
I have a jenkins master defined purely in JSCASC, with pipelines defined using declarative script. I would like to use the startup-trigger-plugin plugin to trigger pipeline jobs remotely via webhook.
The problem appears to have two parts:

Trigger configuration, in CASC, for each pipeline being triggered remotely.
Web authentication token configuration, which should also be configured in JSCASC.

My questions:
a) Is this possible at all using purely JSCASC?
b) Where can I find example working configuration for this scenario?
Sample of my jcasc pipeline jobs section definition:
#Job Definitions using job-dsl plugin
jobs:
  - script: folder('Applications')
  - script: folder('Infrastructure')
  - script: folder('Infrastructure/Production')
  - script: folder('Infrastructure/NonProduction')
  - script: folder('Infrastructure/Production/Bootstrap')
  - script: folder('Infrastructure/NonProduction/Bootstrap')
  - script: folder('Applications/Production')
  - script: folder('Applications/NonProduction')
  - script: folder('Applications/Orchestration')
  - file: /usr/local/enterprise-caf-lz003-app001-nprd.groovy
  - file: /usr/local/enterprise-caf-lz003-app001-prod.groovy
  

